# Клиент на другом компе не подключается к серверу. Java Socket

Tags: java, сервер, сокет, ip

Здравствуйте! Пишу чат с использованием Java Socket. На локальном соединении всё работает(когда запускаю и сервер и клиент на одном компе). Как только пытаюсь запустить с другого компа клиент, он не подключается к серверу. Висит "Ожидание подключения" и с места не сдвигается. 
Код:

**Запуск сервера:**

```
private void runServer(int port, int usercount) throws IOException{ 
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port, usercount, InetAddress.getByName("169.254.187.222")); // Порт, кол-во подключений IP 
    showMessage("Сервер запущен на " + serverSocket.getInetAddress().getByName("ddocprog") + ":" + port, "info"); 
    showMessage("Количество пользователей ограничено! (" + usercount + ")", "info"); 
}
```

**Подключение клиента:**

**ClientRun.java:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws HeadlessException, IOException{ 
    Client client; 
    // Внешний 
    client = new Client("169.254.187.222"); 
    client.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    client.startClient();  
    client.closeConnection(); 
}
```

**Client.java:**

```
public void startClient() throws IOException{ 
    try{ 
        connectToServer(); 
    } 
    catch(EOFException eofException){ // Исключения прерывания диалога  
        showMessage("Клиент оборвал соединение!", "info"); 
    } 
    catch(IOException ioException){ 
        ioException.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
} 

private void connectToServer() throws IOException{ 
    showMessage("Попытка подключения..", "info"); 
    while(true){ 

        try{ 
            Thread.sleep(10); 
        } 
        catch(InterruptedException interruptedException){ 
            interruptedException.printStackTrace(); 
        } 

        try{ 
            socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 7777); 
            showMessage("Вы подключены к " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostName(), "info"); 
            break; 
        } catch(IOException ioException) { 
            ioException.printStackTrace(); 
        } 

    } 

}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, узнать, в чём проблема.

P.S. Чтобы запустить сервер и подключиться к нему клиентом, я использую свой внешний IP адрес.

Comment: Порт на файрволе открыт?

Comment: Да. Вначале создавал правила для порта и для программы(по протоколу TCP). Не помогло. Затем вырубил фаервол к чертям. Снова не помогает(( Это я проделывал на компе с клиентом. На компе с серваком также нужно?

Comment: На сервере тоже нужно. Он же принимает подключение.

Comment: Только что вырубил файерволы на компьютере-сервере и на компьютере-клиенте и протестировал. По прежнему ни в какую. "Ожидание подключения"...(((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, почитайте это [Статический/динамический IP, UDP Java, туннели, Datagram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/738113/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-ip-udp-java-%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-datagram/738399#738399)
Во-вторых, раз у вас через локалхост все коннектится,то искать ошибку в коде нецелесообразно. 
если вы хотите коннектиться в пределах своей локальной сети, то и айпи сервера нужен внутренний,но поскольку 169.254.187.222 не похож на внутренний,  я так понимаю, что это внешний айпи адресс. значит вы пытаетесь коннектиться через инет. тогда обратите внимание на ссылку, которую я дал выше. тут, скорее всего, дело в роутере.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что я не до конца разобрался в условиях работы сервера. Нужно было запустить сервер на устройстве со статическим IP, в то время как у меня динамический. Всем спасибо за ответы :)